# how to use switch statment

Tags: javascript, arrays, switch-statement

im new with JS and i read about the switch statement. i dont know how to use it
i got an exercise to complete.
got an array with numbers 1-10 and the result need to be with words like "one","two","three"..
Thats what i got so far :

```
function sayNum(){
    let nameNumber = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    let text = '';
    for(let i=0;i<nameNumber.length;i++){
    switch(numbers) {
        case "1":
            text = "one";
            break;
        case "2":
            text = "two";
            break;
        case "3":
            text = "three";
            break;
        case "4":
            text='four';
            break;
        case "5":
            text = "five";
            break;
        case "6":
            text = "six";
            break;
        case "7":
            text = "seven";
            break;
        case "8":
            text = "eight";
            break;
        case "9":
            text = "nine";
            break;
        case "10":
            text = "ten";
    }
    }
    return text;
}
sayNum()
```

Comment: Rather than using a `switch`, consider an array that has the values `['one', 'two', ..., 'ten']` and index it by the number (-1)...

Comment: Bunch of issues: 1. `numbers` is undefined and causes the script to fail 2. `text` is overwritten inside the for loop, so the result of the switch block is discarded for all numbers but the last 3. the program doesn't generate any output. Fixed: https://jsfiddle.net/yu74tno8/

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this, for example:

```
function sayNum(){
  let numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
  let result = [];

  for(let i=0;i<numbers.length;i++) {
    switch(numbers[i]) {
        case 1:
            text = "one";
            break;
        case 2:
            text = "two";
            break;
        case 3:
            text = "three";
            break;
        case 4:
            text = "four";
            break;
        case 5:
            text = "five";
            break;
        case 6:
            text = "six";
            break;
        case 7:
            text = "seven";
            break;
        case 8:
            text = "eight";
            break;
        case 9:
            text = "nine";
            break;
        case 10:
            text = "ten";
            break;
    }

    result.push(text);
  }

  return result;
}

let namedNumbers = sayNum();
console.info(namedNumbers);
```

This will:

- Add the textual values to an array, representing each number in the source array
- Return the resulting array to the caller
- Log the result in the `console`

Comment: ...which is still an extremely verbose and inefficient way to transform an array, but I get it, it's for a non-real-life exercise :)

Comment: ... and for someone looking into something clear to start with :)

Answer (score 0):

In the switch statement, you pass an 'expression' into the switch statement. The expression itself can be a string, a number, float, boolean etc. Now, the expression is compared to each of the case clause. And this is a ***'strict'*** comparison. And that is the reason why your code was not working.

Firstly you were passing an undeclared variable, 'numbers' as the switch expression. Instead, you should be passing the `ith` element of the `nameNumber[i]` array like so: `switch(nameNumber[i]){ }`

And, secondly, in each of your case clauses, you are comparing the value to a string like "1", "2". But the switch expression is compared using strict equality `===` operator, therefore when your nameNumber array contains numbers and not strings, your 'case' clauses should also have numbers and not strings. That means `case 1:` instead of `case "1":`.

You can read more about the `switch-case` here: [Switch Statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch#:%7E:text=The%20switch%20statement%20evaluates%20an,that%20follow%20the%20matching%20case%20.)

I have fixed your code below with the changes I mentioned above. Please run the below code snippet to see how it works. Goodluck!

```js
function sayNum(){
    let nameNumber = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    let text = '';
    for(let i=0;i<nameNumber.length;i++){
    switch(nameNumber[i]) {
        case 1:
            text = "one";
            break;
        case 2:
            text = "two";
            break;
        case 3:
            text = "three";
            break;
        case 4:
            text='four';
            break;
        case 5:
            text = "five";
            break;
        case 6:
            text = "six";
            break;
        case 7:
            text = "seven";
            break;
        case 8:
            text = "eight";
            break;
        case 9:
            text = "nine";
            break;
        case 10:
            text = "ten";
    }
    console.log(text);
    }
    return text;
}

sayNum();
```

Comment: Hey :)
Your explanation was great . thank you very much for that !!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a switch, use if statement. Because in switch, break statement can be used to jump out of a loop.

```js
let text = '';

function sayNum() {
  let nameNumber = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
  
  
  for (let i = 0; i < nameNumber.length; i++) {
    if(nameNumber[i] == 1){
    text += `"one",`;
    
    }
    if(nameNumber[i] == 2){
      text += `"two",`;
    }
    if(nameNumber[i] == 3){
      text += `"three",`;
    }

    if(nameNumber[i] == 4){
      text += `"four",`;
    }

    if(nameNumber[i] == 5){
      text += `"five",`;
    }

    if(nameNumber[i] == 6){
      text += `"six",`;
    }

    if(nameNumber[i] == 7){
      text += `"seven",`;
    }

    if(nameNumber[i] == 8){
      text += `"eight",`;
    }

    if(nameNumber[i] == 9){
      text += `"nine",`;
    }

    if(nameNumber[i] == 10){
      text += `"ten"`;
    }

    
  }
  
}

sayNum();

console.log(text)
```